# How to pass an object with private variables from Laravel to Inertia

Tags: laravel, vue.js, domain-driven-design, inertiajs, vue-props

Im new using laravel with inertia 
Version of my laravel is: 9.10.1, Inertia version: 0.11 and Vue: 3.2
I have my class RefundManager

```
class RefundManager
{
    private int $id;
    private string $refund;

    public function __construct(
        int $id,
        string $refund,
    ) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->refund = $refund;
    }

    public function id(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function refund(): string
    {
        return $this->refund;
    }

}
```

I have in my controller an object of that class, and I can access perfectly at $id and $refund through his respective methods id() and refund().
But when I try to pass it to inertia I receive an empty object. Steps:

```
return Inertia::render("Ppo/Sat/RefundCases/Index", [
   'refund' => $myRefundObject
]);
```

In my vue component I have declared prop as object:

```
props: {
  'refund': Object
}
```

And when I change variables $id,$refund to public, then it works.
But when $id and $refund are privates I only receive an empty object and I cannot to access public functions... 
How can I make it works with private variables by accessing them through the public methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a PHP object to a JS object, you need to convert it to a string with json format.

Laravel does it automatically when you send an object to the view by trying to call `toJson()` if defined in the class (by default it is present in Model classes)

So add these two function (will not hurt to add `toArray()` too)

```
/**
 * Convert the object instance to an array.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray()
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'refund' => $this->refund,
    ];
}

/**
 * Convert the object instance to JSON.
 *
 * @param  int  $options
 * @return string
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function toJson($options = 0)
{
    $json = json_encode($this->toArray(), $options);

    if (JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error()) {
        throw new \Exception(json_last_error_msg());
    }

    return $json;
}
```